# Not able to login using firebase login command in cmd

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

receiving this error in the console:

> Error: Failed to make request to https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are in restricted geolocation so you have to use a VPN.

I had the same issue and it solved after using a VPN

I used this one : [Turbo VPN](https://turbovpn.com/download/windows)